# Sharing between iPad aps

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, file-sharing

I have to share a directory created by appA with appB. Is there a way I can "authorize" appB to access the folder created by appA in its space? They are iPad only apps.

I know about UIPasteboard, but I want to share(preferable secure) multiple small files (stored in a folder) created by appA with appB.

I am want to avoid using a server to establish sharing between the apps.

Edit: Both app will be installed on the same device (iPad).

Thank you.
--AAT

Comment: Forgot to mention that both app will be on the same device. Would`nt it then need Internet to download the files?

Comment: Yea, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to do this then.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's provisioning portal:

> In addition, an App ID can also be used to share keychain data (such as passwords) between a suite of applications and share document and configuration data between your applications using iCloud.

So using iCloud, yes you can; otherwise, no.